# AJAX call destroys session wiht no apparent reason

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, session

I know it looks like a banal question but please read the whole thing, I am stumped by this.

I have an AJAX call on one of my pages, it's a dynamic messaging system:

```
function validateMessage(){

  var recipient = document.getElementById("send_to").value;
  var subject = document.getElementById("popup_subject").value;
  var message = document.getElementById("popup_message").value;

  var parameters="message="+message+"&recipient="+recipient+"&subject="+subject;

   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("error_mess").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

  xmlhttp.open("POST","include/send_message.php",false);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  xmlhttp.send(parameters);

  }
```

It's implemented as synchronous for a reason, that's not the issue here. I tried switching to asynchronous and the problem remains.

This is the send_message.php file, it just grabs the POST variables and saves them into the database:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('db.php');
dbConnect();

$message=$_POST['message'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$recipient=$_POST['recipient'];

$result=mysql_query("select * from korisnici where username='$recipient' ") or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($recipient=="Poruka za..." || $subject=="Naslov..." || $message=="Poruka" || $recipient=="" || $subject=="" || $message=="")
    echo "<p style='color:red;'>Morate popuniti sva polja.</p>";
elseif($num==0)
    echo "<p style='color:red;'>Korisnik ne postoji.</p>";
else{
    $prima=$row['id_user'];
    $salje=$_SESSION['id_user'];
    mysql_query("insert into poruke (salje, prima, naslov, poruka)
        values ('$salje', '$prima', '$subject', '$message') ") or die(mysql_error());
    echo "<p style='color:green;'>Poruka uspješno poslata!</p>";
}

?>
```

However, when I tried to save the $_SESSION['id_user'] variable (as the sender) I found a problem - it turns out the session is being destroyed every time this AJAX call runs! So doing `print_r($_SESSION)` right after `session_start()` prints an empty array.

The session is alive on the original page itself, and refreshing that page keeps the session alive. Only when I click the button to make the AJAX call, the session disappears. Can someone spot the issue?

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the visible code. Nothing here should be destroying the session variable.

Comment: I'm pretty certain of that too. What could be a possible cause for this, then? Never happened to me before. There's really no code involved other than what I've posted. The original page (that the call is made from) doesn't even mention any session stuff except for session_start() in the beginning of the page.

Comment: I've seen problems like this before, and the problem was a misconfigured PHP server. I've also seen similar problems dealing with the browser, since sessions use cookies. You might want to download and try out a different browser just to be sure. It could also be a problem with some code somewhere else. Can't really say from what I see here.

Comment: Same thing happens in other browsers. As for the server, it's on a shared server which I've been using for development for years, never had this problem. I suppose I'll try to dump this on their support, I'm completely out of ideas here.

Comment: The times I've seen it happen with misconfigured servers, it will intermittently have problems with any PHP program that uses sessions. I suggest you make a super simple program that uses sessions, then just refresh it over and over to see if the session ever breaks.

Comment: Is your server and browser time proper?

Comment: I've seen this problem when a php.ini/.htaccess file has messed up a path so the session gets lost when the browser is navigating from certain directories on the server(even though they are under the same website/domain directory).

Comment: Could it be that the session ID is changed between the main page and the AJAX call?

Comment: Sorry for being late, had to leave the house.

AT shiplu.mokadd.im Should be, everything was ok a few hours ago, and nothing separates this page from others.

@Josh But I haven't changed anything in php.ini or .htaccess, they can't change spontaniously can they?

AT JonathanAmend I don't see why that would be happening but I'll check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution, as given to me by he technical support team of my hosting provider:

Set suhosin.session.encrypt=Off in /home/username/public_html

Set suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html in .htaccess.

And that's it, works now. No time to investigate these settings at this point, but I hope this will help someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

please check the form starts and ends and very important please check whether you have given button as onclick with return false.if not then it will redirect and gives you no session there.